# Mac Mini connecting to Airport Extreme at only 802.11a, how to push to 802.11b/g/n?

Tags: macos, networking, mac-mini, airport, 802.11n

My Mac Mini is capable of 802.11a/b/g.  I have an Airport Extreme that is capable of 802.11a/b/g/n.  The Mini connects at only 802.11a.  It is close and has a very strong signal.  How do I push the Mini to reconnect at 802.11g?

Update: I'm using Airport Utility version 5.5.x.

Comment: I have no experience with Airport Extreme, but can you disable `802.11a/b` ?

Comment: Update:  I called Apple.  Their tech showed me how to do what Kami suggested (albeit with Airport Utility 5.5 which has a slightly different interface).  My Mini immediately jumped to 802.11g.  Awesome... Thank the tech and on my way to speedier surfing... Later in the day I lost my connection.  No matter what I could not reconnect even though the Airport was listed with a strong signal.  Looking in the console I see an unexplained error.  So I get my 16' CAT5, and change the setting back.  Airport connects immediately, no problem, at 802.11a.  <Sigh>

Comment: I don't understand why you'd want to switch to B/G when you can do A. A and G have the exact same rate set, just in different bands. 802.11a works in the generally less-noisy 5GHz band, whereas 802.11g works in the noisier 2.4GHz band same as 802.11b.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable "a" mode in your Airport Extreme !

Air Port Utility -> Your AE -> Manual Setup -> Wireless -> Radio Mode

[image]

To check what wireless mode your Mac mini is using, click at the wireless icon (top right of your screen) while holding <kbd>alt</kbd> :

[image]

Finally go to System Profiler -> Network -> Airport -> Supported PHY Modes to ensure Mac mini supported modes

Comment: Since the Mini can not communicate at 802.11n, this would be a bad idea.

Comment: 802.11n (b/g compatible) !!!

Comment: Doesn't it say so in the images?

Comment: Ok, but my Airport Utility has different choices.  I'm using version 5.5.  It lists: Automatic, 802.11a/n - 802.11b/g, and 802.11a - 802.11b/g.  I tried them all and the Mini connects at 802.11a.

Comment: Have you updated your Airport Extreme ?

Comment: In version 5.5 of the Airport Utility, you must hold down the alt key to get a full list of choices from the "Radio Mode" menu.  But see my general comment above where a explained the results.